# Strange behavior of sscanf

Tags: c, scanf

I found some strange thing. Here is example of code:

```
...
char *start = strchr(value, '(');
if(start)
{
    char buf[LEN];
    memset(buf, 0, LEN);
    int num = sscanf(start, "(%s)", buf);
    if(num)
    {
        buf[strlen(buf) - 1] = '\0';
        sprintf(value, "%s", buf);
    }
...
```

if value is "(xxx)", for example, then value  will be "xxx" after this actions. 
But if value is "([34]xx{4,7}| 1234567890)" then value will be "[34]xx{4,7}". 
Can anyone explain it?

P.S. it's ARM platform.

Comment: what is the actual output you are getting?

Comment: strlen(buf) should not be used if string is not having \0 at end.

Comment: `sscanf()` with `%s` stops reading when it encounters whitespace. There is a space after the `|` character. The code then overwrites the `|` character.

Comment: @hmjd, this is the answer. why not put it as answer?

Comment: hmjd, should not num is zero in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int num = sscanf(start, "(%s)", buf);
```

Here, `sscanf` returns when it encounters a whitespace in the buffer pointed to by `start`. You have a space in your input string:

```
"([34]xx{4,7}| 1234567890)"
              ^ space here
```

`scanf` returns the number of input items successfully matched and assigned. Here, it will return `1` and the value of `num` is `1`. Next, you overwrite the last character in `buf` by this statement in your `if` block.

```
buf[strlen(buf) - 1] = '\0';
```

That explains your program's output. Now, a few things about your code:

You don't need to do `memset(buf, 0, LEN);`. Simply do `char buf[LEN] = {0};` This fills the array with the null byte.

`sscanf` doesn't check for the array bound of the buffer `buf` into which you are writing the string which `sscanf` is reading from `start`. If the size of `buf` is not enough, `sscanf` will try to write in the memory beyond the buffer `buf`. This will lead to undefined behaviour and even program crash because of illegal memory access. You should give field width in the format string of `sscanf` to guard against the buffer overrun.

```
#define STRINGIFY(s) #s  // preprocessor command # stringifies the token s
#define XSTRINGIFY(s) STRINGIFY(s)
#define LEN 10    // max buffer length without the null byte   

// inside a function

char buf[LEN + 1];   // +1 for the null byte
const char *format = "(" XSTRINGIFY(LEN) "%s)";  // "(%10s)"
int num = sscanf(start, format, buf);
```

The `10` in the format string `"(%10s)"` means that at most `10` characters are stored in the buffer pointed to by `buf` and then a null byte `\0` is added automatically in the end. Hence you don't need the following in the `if` block:

```
buf[strlen(buf) - 1] = '\0'; // overwrites the last char before null byte in buf.
```

Doing this, in fact, overwrites the last character in `buf` because `strlen` doesn't count the null byte.

Answer (score 1):

sscanf is used with %s, when it encounters whitespace it will terminate. That is the reason you are getting the output as "[34]xx{4,7}" instead of expected behaviour

Comment: should not num is zero in this case?

Comment: sscanf return number of chars it processed. so it will not be zero

Comment: @arunb2w `scanf` returns the number of input *items* successfully matched and assigned, not the number of characters processed.

Comment: I just wanted to say it.

Answer (score 1):

> The format string consists of a sequence of directives which describe how to process the sequence of input characters. If processing of a directive fails, no further input is read, and scanf() returns. A "failure" can be either of the following: input failure, meaning that input characters were unavailable, or matching failure, meaning that the input was inappropriate (see below).

In your case, `sscanf` matches the starting `(`, and then parses the next token, `%s` which consumes data up to the first whitespace character. `sscanf` then fails to match a `)`, which means that the parsing stops. One token was successfully read and assigned, so the return value is `1`.

Note that when using `scanf`, you cannot detect matching failures that occur after the last token that is assigned.